# can't create release app package for store UWP

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cordova, ionic-framework, uwp

I am creating an application with Ionic / Cordova that must work on Windows 10. The application works well when I build it from Visual Studio in "debug" and "x64" configuration. But when I want to create an app package from "Project" > "Store" > "Create App Package", it fails with error :

```
Error MSB6006 "ilc.exe" exited with code 1200
```

Digging deeper, I can find in the output tab the error :

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Le nom de propriété "MSBuildToolsPath" est réservé
```

It's in French, I can't get the equivalent in English, it seems to mean "Property name MSBuildToolsPath is reserved"

Complete error message :

```
Task "LoggerBasedExecTask"
1>    Task Parameter:Application=C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\.Net\.NetNative\15.0.24211\x86\ilc\ilc.exe
1>    Task Parameter:Parameters=@"build\windows\bld\ilc.CordovaApp.Windows10.rsp"
1>    Task Parameter:MessageLog=C:\QUALIOS\Sources\QualiosMobile_LW\Qualios\platforms\windows\build\windows\bld\ilc\ilclog.csv
1>    Task Parameter:UseCommandProcessor=False
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\.Net\.NetNative\15.0.24211\x86\ilc\ilc.exe @"build\windows\bld\ilc.CordovaApp.Windows10.rsp" "/logger:CsvLogger;3472;3460"
1>    System.InvalidOperationException: Le nom de propriété "MSBuildToolsPath" est réservé.
1>       à Microsoft.Build.Shared.ErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidOperation(String resourceName, Object[] args)
1>       à Microsoft.Build.Shared.ErrorUtilities.VerifyThrowInvalidOperation(Boolean condition, String resourceName, Object arg0)
1>       à Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectPropertyElement.CreateDisconnected(String name, ProjectRootElement containingProject)
1>       à Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectPropertyGroupElement.AddProperty(String name, String unevaluatedValue)
1>       à Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement.AddProperty(String name, String value)
1>       à ilc.Program.AddPropertiesToBlockEnvironmentVariables(ProjectRootElement rootElement)
1>       à ilc.Program.PrepareAndRunMsbuildTargets(Package package, String intermediatesFolderName, Boolean isAppX)
1>       à ilc.Program.RunIlc(String intermediatesFolderName)
1>       à ilc.Program.InnerMain(String[] args)
1>       à ilc.Program.Main(String[] args)
1>    ILC.exe has experienced an unexpected error. Please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613098 for a list of known issues.
1>
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\.Net\.NetNative\15.0.24211\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(640,5): error MSB6006: "ilc.exe" exited with code 1200.
1>    Output Property: _IlcExitCode=1200
1>  Done executing task "LoggerBasedExecTask" -- FAILED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found solution !

I just had to install globally windows-build-tools to get it work. Cordova apparently needs it

```
npm install -g windows-build-tools
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time those errors are fixed by updating to the latest .NET Native *(Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform)* package.

Can you try to update to the latest version (6.2.8)? https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/releases/UWP/net-native2.2/README.md

Comment: I tried to launch Install-Package Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform -Version 6.2.8
but I get Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.NETCore.Jit 1.0.3'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'UAP,Version=v10.0.10240', but the package does not contain any 
assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author

Comment: Which version of VS, .Net and SDK are you using?

Comment: VS : 15.3.5
.Net : 4.7.2
SDK Windows 10 (10.0.15063.0)

Comment: I don't think i'm supposed to use Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform with cordova, if I search for installed nugets, it says "no package found". My colleague has the same project as me and can build in release